# do while and right shifting has without effect

Tags: c, do-while

```
int i=1,j=0,n=10,k;
do{
    j+=i;
    i<<1;
    printf("%d\n",i);
   // printf("%d\n",12<<1);
}while(i<=n);
printf("%d\n",j);
```

In the while loop,the shift operator works(12<<1 =24) but `i<<1` remain 0.J is increasing continuously.If I change n with 0 the loop will stop,that is normal but the incrementation of `i` will never happen.

I can shift in any direction and still doesn't work.

Comment: Typo `i<<1` should be `i<<=1`. Please enable compiler warnings: it should warn you. For example the warning from MSVC is *warning C4552: '<<': operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect.*

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks a lot,I will look at warnings in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `i << 1` doesn't affect the value of `i`. What you may be looking for is

```
i = i << 1;
```

or perhaps one of the following, which do the same:

```
i <<= 1;
i = i * 2;
i *= 2;
```

**Note**: only if `i >= 0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: Note: with `int i` and `i < 0`  (not OP's code), `i *= 2` is only UB when it overflows.  `i <<= 1;` is always UB.  So not always the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` operator is not working in-place. You have to assign a result somewhere. For example:

```
i = i << 1;
```

or

```
i <<= 1;
```

which is the same as above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution,but I'm so sorry because I got another answer as yours and the other one replied faster and I have to choose him for the correct answer :(

Comment: That's OK, we have this competition here all the time :)